# Connect to DB2 on a system with multiple python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I have a system with python 3.6 and I also alt installed 3.9.

I am using ibm_db and ibm-db_dbi packages and when I connect to DB using python3.6 connection works fine. But when I connect using python 3.9 it fails with:

```
>>> ibm_db.connect(dsn2, "","")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019 SQLCODE=-1032
```

Even with ibm_db_dbi I get the same error. I verified the ssl certs and they are being picked up correctly.

dsn2 = `'DATABASE=MYDB;UID=db2inst1;PWD=XXXXXXXX;PORT=50001;PROTOCOL=SSL;HOSTNAME=myhost;SSLClientKeyStoreDB=/usr/local/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/component/rest/data/ssl'`

No errors in diag logs. Any pointers to why is the connection not working? Is it looking for something in python3.6 which is missing in 3.9?

I have made an alt install of python3.9. So both 3.6 and 3.9 co exist. and I open python interpreter of different versions to run the command. OS is Centos. If I remove `SSL` from dsn connection works fine on 3.9 as well.

Comment: What is the operating system?  How do you switch between Python versions?  Are you running different versions of python in different shells?   please edit your question with clarifications, Do not use comments because comments are not searchable.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Is the `ibm_db.connect(...` the only statement, in both Python versions with the same DSN? Did you install the Db2 driver to both environments?

Comment: yes I installed driver in both the environments. ibm_db.connect if the only statement failing on 3.9 and working fine one 3.6 with the same connection string. If I remove SSL connection works fine. (updating the question with this informantion)

Comment: @codec ,  problem lies not with Python or ibm_db but with your config. Prove this by connecting to the same DSN with the same credentials WITH SSSL at the bash command line with the `db2cli` command for both versions (it lives in the clidriver/bin directory, refer to Db2 docs for its command line e.g. `db2cli -connect -dsn ... -user ... -passwd ... ` (need to config `db2dsdriver.cfg` first, see docs).  If you are using the same keystore file (one copy of it) and same stash file, and the same system-account to run both pythons then check file/directory permissions/ownerships etc.

Comment: I used PROTOCOL=TCPIP and SECURITY=SSL and now the connection works.